Age function computes differently when used through a view in PostgreSQL FDW
I have a view which has a column for age (like Age (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, birth_dtm)). This works fine, but when used through a FDW offsets the age by current timezone's offset from GMT. PostgreSQL documentation states that postegersql_FDW sets the TIMEZONE to UTC. How do we work around it?
Consider the following table definition, the data in the table and a view based on the table:
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id      serial  PRIMARY KEY,
    birth_dtm   TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO test (birth_dtm) VALUES ('2024-03-22 08:23', '2024-03-07 13:19', '2024-03-24 01:06);
CREATE VIEW view_test AS
    SELECT  id, birth_dtm, AGE (current_timestamp, birth_dtm) c_age
    FROM    test;

Now when we execute the statement in a foreign database where this VIEW is available:
SELECT *, AGE (current_timestamp, birth_dtm)
FROM    FDB.view_test;

We get the following output:



id
birth_dtm
c_age
age




1
2024-03-22 08:23
20 days 07:31:44.651565
20 days 13:01:44.651323


2
2024-03-07 13:19
1 mon 4 days 02:35:44.651565
1 mon 4 days 08:05:44.651323


3
2024-03-24 01:06
18 days 14:48:44.651565
18 days 20:18:44.651323



So my question is how to achieve the Output in Column 3 (view_test.c_age) as shown in Column 4?
Note that the difference is 5.30 between column 3 and column 4 is as per TIME ZONE Asia/Kolkata.

Use LOCALTIMESTAMP instead of current_timestamp, that would ignore any time zone. Your column birth_dtm is without a time zone anyways.

Thanks @FrankHeikens. It works in the simple scenario presented here, but it did not work in a complex function that I am using. At some point of time (when I have time), I intend to get to the bottom of it as to where the fix is needed.

The cause of the problem is the questionable choice of the data type timestamp without time zone for birth_dtm. timestamp with time zone would have been the appropriate data type.
Since you (or somebody else) chose timestamp, the timestamp is time zone unaware, and the interpretation will vary according to the time zone of the reader. But a birth is an absolute event, so it must be that the time zone is implicitly assumed. If, for example, the database is in India and stores only Indian births for an Indian application, one could choose timestamp and tacitly assume that all timestamps are understood to be in the Indian time zone.
In that case, you should change your view definition to reflect that assumption. Otherwise, the data returned will depend on the time zone of the observer. If all your timestamps are in Indian time, the view definition should be
CREATE VIEW view_test AS
SELECT id, birth_dtm,
       AGE (current_timestamp, birth_dtm AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata') c_age
FROM test;


Thanks @laurenz-albe. I will like to know the scenarios as to when to use timestamp and when to use timestamp without time zone. For example, what should be the choice of data-type for transaction_date_time?

Three guidelines: If you manage time zones in the application, you can use either type in the database. If you want PostgreSQL to manage time zones, use timestamp with time zone. Use the same data type everywhere in the database.
